# I can't get the text in the TextBox roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

I want to get a text field that the user modifies, but I don't get anything in the output

```
script.Parent.MouseClick:Connect(function(plr)
    print(game.Players[plr.Name].PlayerGui.ScreenGui.Frame.TextBox.Text)
end)
```

I tried using Local script, but it didn't lead to a result either

Answer (score 0):

The MouseButton1Click callback does not receive any parameter hence you must get the player instance using `local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a easier way

First, you need to use a **Local Script**. Next, enter the code I give you below. But before that, please confirm that your local script is **inside the Textbox**.

```
script.Parent.FocusLost:Connect(function(enter) 
    if enter then --see if the player has finished the input
        print(script.Parent.Text) -- prints out the text 
    end
end)
```

Thats all, hope you knows how to do.